# In Rails 5.1+, how can I find out the initial value of an attribute when I don't know if I'm in an after_save hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm currently in the process of upgrading from Rails 5.0 to Rails 5.1. One of the changes is in `ActiveRecord::Dirty`, described in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/16ae3db5a5c6a08383b974ae6c96faac5b4a3c81. In short, the method `attribute_was` is now deprecated, because its behavior is different depending on whether you are currently in an `after_save` hook or beyond it.

According to that description, there should be an equivalent method in Rails 5.1, but I haven't been able to find out. In particular, I wonder how to solve the scenario below.

Suppose I am handling a web request and am processing a record with an attribute A that has some initial value V1 (which could be `nil`).

- At time t1, I may or may not change A from V1 to V2
- At time t2, when **I don’t know** if I am in an `after_save` hook or `before_save` (or haven't even called `save` yet), I want to know what the initial value of A was, and the answer should be `V1`. How can I find out?

  - Calling `A_before_last_save` returns `nil` when I’m in a before_save hook and V1 in an after_save hook
  - Calling `A_in_database` returns V1 when I’m in a before_save hook and V2 in an after_save hook
  - Calling `A_was` currently returns the correct value V1 both before_save and after_save, but shows a deprecation warning that it will start to return V2 in the after_save hook in a future Rails version.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to accomplish this?